# VMDK descriptor file format

Tags: vmware, virtual-disk

I would like to create a VMDK descriptor file for a dd image so that this image file can be used as a VMDK and attached to a VM.

I am able to find articles like http://justaskweg.com/?p=959 and http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1002511.  But I cannot find something that would describe the file format exactly so that I could create the file with confidence.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer for my own question http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vddk/vmdk_50_technote.pdf

And this one also helps http://sanbarrow.com/vmdk-basics.html#cidchain